# Incluir um dígito antes do telefone nos cadastro do BD

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um sistema onde foi cadastrado 18 mil usuários, porém percebi que os telefones de celular e fixo estão faltando um dígito. Ex.: (21)9999-999 ou (21)2222-222. Apesar do campo ser CHAR(14). Tem como incluir diretamente o número 9 (no caso do celular) e o número 2 (no caso do fixo) em todos os cadastros de uma só vez? Pode ser no php ou diretamente no Mysql.

Comment: Olá Wallace, quase.. rs rs rs... o caso do outro colega é menos grave que o meu, pois o meu já está cadastrado rs rs rs... gostaria de incluir o dígito nos registros que já foram cadastrados no banco de dados...

Comment: Acho que o problema é mais sério do que imaginei. Usando o exemplo do link que o Wallace passou, ficou: (21)999999-999. Observe que ficou uniforme.

Comment: Aí você teria que verificar quantos dígitos tem antes

Comment: Olá Wallace. Perdoe-me o abuso, mas é que não estou encontrando um raciocínio lógico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente esse código:

> UPDATE telefones SET tel = REPLACE(tel, '(21)', '(21)9');

O método REPLACE substitui uma string por outra, nesse caso ele vai substituir uma parte da string por outra que contém o 9º dígito.

No entanto se os telefones são todos iguais recomendaria esse código:

> UPTADE telefones SET tel = REPLACE(tel, '(21)999999-999', '(21)99999-9999');

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se vai dar certo com o MySQL, mas no sql server eu faria da seguinte forma.

```
declare @Celular varchar(14) = '(21)9999-999'


declare @NovoCelular varchar(14) 



set @NovoCelular = case when LEN(@Celular) = 12   --  LEN = LENGTH no mysql
    then  replace((LEFT(@Celular, 4) + '9' + RIGHT(@Celular, LEN(@Celular) - 4)),'-', '' )
    else @Celular
    end

set @Celular = LEFT(@NovoCelular, 8) + '-' + RIGHT(@NovoCelular, LEN(@NovoCelular) - 8)

select @Celular
```

É uma ideia de como fazer, basta monta a sua query com os filtro necessário .